# Как узнать, как подключена библиотека androidx.swiperefreshlayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout, androidx

В проекте используется `SwipeRefreshLayout` из *AndroidX*. Например, в файле объявлен следующий импорт:

```
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
```

и всё работает. Проблема только в том, что я не могу найти, где именно подключается эта библиотека. При открытии класса этой библиотеки в окне *Project* видно следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из чего я заключила, что эта библиотека должна подключаться как строка вида

```
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:..."
```

в *build.gradle* файле (а также из названия библиотеки [на оф. сайте](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)), однако поиском по проекту и по *build.gradle* файлам  такой строки не нахожу. Или же эта библиотека входит в состав какой-то другой, например, *androidx.legacy*?

Как можно узнать, где подключается эта библиотека?

**UPD**

Выполнение таска *Project->:module->Tasks->help->dependencies* выводит в консоль такое дерево зависимостей:

```
appDebugCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'debugConfiguration' (target  (androidJvm)).
+--- ...
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0
|    \--- androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0
|         +--- ...
|         +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
|         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
|         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
|         |    |    +--- ...
|         |    |    +--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
|         |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
|         |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 (*)
|         |    |    |    \--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- ...
|         |    +--- ...
|         +--- ...
+--- ...
+--- ...
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0 (*)
+--- ...
```

Comment: `View > Tool Windows > Gradle`, раскрыть дерево и выполнить таск `Project->:module->Tasks->help->dependensies` - это выведет в консоль дерево зависимостей, там можно посмотреть кто что притащил.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо! выполнила этот таск, но не всё равно не понятно, что значит его вывод... (обновила пост, добавила этот вывод)

Comment: Первое: `androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0` зависит от перечисленных артефактов (в том числе, по цепочке от `swiperefreshlayout`). Второе: корневая запись означает, что она таки ещё и самостоятельно прописана в `gradle.build` этого модуля или проекта. Непонятно только почему Вы её не нашли... её точно там нет?

Comment: @woesss, вроде нет - искала и поиском по проекту Android Studio и поиском по build.gradle файлам

Comment: По строке "implement ..." или "swiperefreshlayout"? Но даже если её нет, то она подтягивается по цепочке зависимостей `androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0 -> androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.core:core:1.0.0 (*) -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 -> androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0`. Всё это в проекте не прописано - у каждого артефакта в мавен-репозитории есть файл `pom-xml`, в котором описано от чего он зависит и другая полезная информация.

Comment: Gradle при обработке зависимостей читает их pom-файлы, скачивает всю цепочку и добавляет в classpath.